# Copying files in a directory using memcpy and mmap forcing all files to be 1Byte

Tags: c, multithreading

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

void* copyFile(void* arg) {

    char *filename = ((char*)arg);

    char *destname = strcat(filename, "copy");

    int in = 0;
    in = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

    int out = 0;
    out = open(destname, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

    struct stat statbuf;
    fstat(in, &statbuf);   

    off_t insize = statbuf.st_size;
    lseek(out, insize - 1, SEEK_SET);
    ssize_t wrote = write(out, "", 1);

    char* inmap = mmap(0, insize, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, in, 0);

    char* outmap = mmap(0, insize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, out, 0);

    memcpy(outmap, inmap, insize);

    close(out);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  DIR* d;
  struct dirent* e;

  d = opendir(argv[1]);

  int num_entries = 0;

  int i = 0;

  pthread_t threads[50];

  while((e = readdir(d)) != NULL) {

    char *filename = e->d_name;

    printf("%s\n", filename);

    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, copyFile, filename);    

    i++;
  }

  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

    pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);

  }

}
```

Hello, I am attempting to use mmap and memcpy to copy an entire directory of files using multithreading. I've got the code to copy the files in the directory, however it is forcing all COPIED files to be 1 Byte in size. I'm curious as to why this is happening and what can be done to resolve this bug.

I am very much a novice at C so please forgive my obvious semantic errors. I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Do you need to do something like "read first" then "read next"? Also are you modifying the directory as you read entries from it?

Comment: I was under the impression that the while loop is iterating through the directory stream and thus wouldn't need a 'read first' or 'read next'. Also I am not modifying the directory to my knowledge.

Comment: `readdir` returns a pointer to a structure that may be statically allocated.  That means you may be passing the same value of `filename` to all threaded instances of `copyFile`.

Comment: @G.M. For example, if we had 3 files `f1` `f2` `f3` would we expect the output to be 3 instances of `f1copy` in accordance with your proposed error? If that is the case, unfortunately that is not what I am experiencing, the names are all correctly coming in (though I hope I am just understanding your explanation wrong and you are correct!).

Comment: Also `strcat` modifies the string it is passed.  So if `filename` was `"foo"`, then `char *destname = strcat(filename, "copy");` results in `filename` being `foocopy` and `destname` being another pointer to the same string.  And anyway, `filename` is a pointer to the buffer returned by `readdir`, which you are not supposed to modify (especially because held by other threads).  You need to make a temporary buffer to hold `destname`.

Comment: Does it work without multithreading? If so, you haven't provided a [mcve], which makes your question off-topic. As a relatively new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No, OP's program does _not_ work even without multithreading. See my answer for a list of bugs, most of which would be present even in the single threaded case.

Comment: `close(out) ` is closing the file descriptor, but does not interact with the mapping. To reliably propagate changes done to a mmap-ed memory region to the in-storage file you'll have to call `msync` on the altered region, or unmap the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors.

1. In `main`, `filename` will point to the *same* address for all files. We must provide a *unique* address/copy. One way is to use `strdup`. And, we should add a `free` call at the bottom of `copyFile` to release the storage allocated by the `strdup`.
2. We must skip over `.` and `..` when copying. Otherwise, the code segfaults.
3. Using the same directory for input files and the copy can cause the equivalent of an infinite loop. That is, given a file `xyz` that is copied to `xyzcopy`, the `readdir` may be able to see `xyzcopy` as input and try to create `xyzcopycopy`.
   Better to use a separate output directory. That would require a major rewrite. But, a simpler fix is to skip any file that contains `copy`.
4. The program will [try to] copy directory entries even if they are *not* ordinary files (e.g. it would try to do `open` on a *directory*). We should check the file type and skip non-file types.
5. In `copyFile`, even with the `strdup` in `main`, the string `filename` does *not* have enough space to allow for the `strcat` of `"copy"`. We need a separate buffer for the output filename.
6. The `lseek/write` adds a superfluous binary zero at the end of the output file. This is to extend the output file. Better to use `ftruncate` for that.
7. That's because intermixing `write` with `mmap` *can* be problematic and is *usually* not the best practice. In your use case, it *may* be okay (because the `write` is done *before* the `mmap`), but if we go to the trouble to use `mmap`, it's better to *just* use the `mmap` buffer pointer and `memcpy`.
8. `copyFile` is missing a `return`. And, `main` is also missing a `return`
9. There is no `close` for `in` in `copyFile`.
10. There is no error checking on `open`, `mmap`, `opendir` calls.
11. There should be `munmap` calls before the `close` calls.

---

Bugs *not* fixed:

1. The program is limited in how many entries the directory can have.
2. With `pthread_t threads[50];` we can *only* have 50 entries in the directory. There is *no* check for overflow of this array.
3. It makes *no* practical sense to do *all* files in parallel. This does *not* scale.
4. If we had (e.g.) 1,000,000 entries in the directory, we could run out of resources. We could run out of unused process slots and `pthread_create` would start to fail after a system wide limit is reached. We could run out of file descriptors and the `open` calls would begin to fail after approximately 1024 open files.
5. After a set number of threads is created (e.g. in practice, 4-5), the copying process would actually be *slower* because the system would spend most of its time switching between the threads rather than doing useful work.
6. For small files, the overhead of thread creation/teardown becomes significant relative to the running time of the thread.

It would be better to have a limited "pool" of "worker" threads, and intersperse the `pthread_create` calls with `pthread_join` calls, reclaiming/reusing the now unused/free "slot" when a thread completes.

A more efficient way would be to create the pool of threads (via `pthread_create` calls *once* at the start. Each thread would have a mailbox/queue of work to do. `main` could enqueue the entries to the threads, adding a new entry when it sees a thread become idle. The `pthread_join` calls could be done *once* at the end

---

Below is the corrected code.

I used preprocessor conditionals to denote old vs. new code (e.g.):

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

---

Anyway, here is the corrected code. I've annotated the bugs/fixes with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

void *
copyFile(void *arg)
{

// NOTE/BUG: no cast is needed from a void *
#if 0
    char *filename = ((char *) arg);
#else
    char *filename = arg;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: there is _not_ enough space in filename to add "copy" -- this is
// UB (undefined behavior)
#if 0
    char *destname = strcat(filename, "copy");
#else
    char destname[1024];
    strcpy(destname,filename);
    strcat(destname,"copy");
#endif

    int in = 0;

    in = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

// NOTE/FIX: check for error
#if 1
    if (in < 0) {
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    int out = 0;

    out = open(destname, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,
        S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

// NOTE/FIX: check for error
#if 1
    if (out < 0) {
        perror(destname);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    struct stat statbuf;

    fstat(in, &statbuf);

    off_t insize = statbuf.st_size;

// NOTE/BUG: this will add a binary zero at the end of the output file
#if 0
    lseek(out, insize - 1, SEEK_SET);
    ssize_t wrote = write(out, "", 1);
#else
    ftruncate(out,insize);
#endif

    char *inmap = mmap(0, insize, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, in, 0);

// NOTE/FIX: check for error
#if 1
    if (inmap == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap/in");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    char *outmap = mmap(0, insize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, out, 0);

// NOTE/FIX: check for error
#if 1
    if (inmap == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap/in");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    memcpy(outmap, inmap, insize);

// NOTE/FIX: we should unamp the output area
#if 1
    munmap(outmap,insize);
#endif

    close(out);

// NOTE/FIX: we should unmap and close the input descriptor
#if 1
    munmap(inmap,insize);
    close(in);
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: free the string allocated by strdup in main
#if 1
    free(filename);
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: needs return value -- would be flagged by compiler if compiled
// with -Wall
#if 1
    return (void *) 0;
#endif
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *e;

// NOTE/BUG: no checks for missing argument or bad directory
#if 0
    d = opendir(argv[1]);
#else
    if (argv[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"missing argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    d = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (d == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: unused variable
#if 0
    int num_entries = 0;
#endif

    int i = 0;

    pthread_t threads[50];

    while ((e = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
// NOTE/FIX: must skip "." and ".."
#if 1
        if (strcmp(e->d_name,".") == 0)
            continue;
        if (strcmp(e->d_name,"..") == 0)
            continue;
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: only copy simple files (i.e. do _not_ copy subdirectories, etc.)
#if 1
        if (e->d_type != DT_REG)
            continue;
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: skip "copy" files
#if 1
        if (strstr(e->d_name,"copy") != NULL)
            continue;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: this will present the _same_ memory address to all threads so there
// is a "race condition"
#if 0
        char *filename = e->d_name;
#else
        char *filename = strdup(e->d_name);
#endif

        printf("%s\n", filename);

        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, copyFile, filename);

        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
    }

// NOTE/FIX: needs return
#if 1
    return 0;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! This worked!